# Save File to Specific Location Using PHP

Tags: php, excel, download

I have a PHP script that is writing an Excel file.  The script is successfully writing the file, but is saving it in the same directory as the script.

I want the user to be able to see the "Save As" dialog window when they click the Download button that I have.  Everything I have seen regarding how to do this in PHP has said to just add this to the PHP script:

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="video.m4v"');`

where "video.m4v" would be the Excel file I am downloading.

However, the "Save As" window never pops up, and it continues to save it to the same directory as the script.  Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: How are you "saving" the file?  You're describing a server-side save, but the header you mention is for sending the file to the client.  The two are very different things.

Comment: I want the file to be saved to the client side.

Comment: What other headers are you sending (and since when was .m4v an Excel file extension)?

Comment: As I said, the m4v was just because I pasted it from somewhere else. Obviously I want .xlsx or .xls.

Comment: @snowfi6916: Can you show the code that you're using to send the file to the client?  It sounds like you're saving the file on the server-side instead.

Comment: @snowfi6916 You need to post your full in order for someone, probably maybe even myself, to help you better. One line of code is not enough in this case. However adding this may do the trick `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("video.m4v"));`

Comment: I found it.  If I set "window.location" in the JS that I am using to call the PHP script, and set the location to be where it is downloading the file to on the server, I can get the client window to pop up asking where to download it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to do it strictly with PHP without realizing I could do it with JS.

Comment: @snowfi6916 What will you do if someone has JS disabled? Your new solution won't work and you'll be back here again, asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
<a href="video.m4v" download>Click here to download</a>
```

be sure to include the word "download" after the filename

Comment: the file is simpty downloaded, no save us appears.